# Duplicate javascript references

Tags: javascript

I have the to give some javascript to my clients to put on their pages.
That javascript code injects on my client pages reference to some javascript in my server.
Similar to this:

```
if (typeof MYSUPERVAR == 'undefined') {
      var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
      var script = document.createElement('script');
      script.src = '//mywebsite.com/myjs.js';
      script.async = true;
      script.type = 'text/javascript';
      head.appendChild(script);
   }
   //After JS is loaded call MYJS_FUNCTION_A
   MYJS_FUNCTION_A()
```

"myjs" creates MYSUPERVAR and also creates a function that should be called for each time that the user wants (by adding the same javascript).
This is for adding some images functionality so the user has to put every time the script with the imageid. 
The problem is that this creates a script reference for myjs all the time.

It's possible to know if myjs is correctly loaded before adding one more reference?

Comment: If `myjs` wasn't loaded, your function wouldn't be created. So why do you need to load the file again?

Comment: I want to give pictures a functionality so every picture will have this same script. But I want to myjs only one time.

Answer (score 1):

you can load js file and call callback function after loaded finish.

```
<script>
function loadJS(src, callback) {
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.src = src;
    s.async = true;
    s.onreadystatechange = s.onload = function() {
        var state = s.readyState;
        if (!callback.done && (!state || /loaded|complete/.test(state))) {
            callback.done = true;
            callback();
        }
    };
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
}
loadJS('/script/script.js', function() { 
    // put your code here to run after script is loaded
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi omid... Thanks for the answer but i'm afraid that is my actual problem. In that case in clients page there would be a <script scr="/script/script.js"></script> for all the times the client puts that script.

Comment: above code is not solve your problem?
what you don't use jquery?

Comment: why you try to add existing script?

Comment: You could use `document.head` instead of `document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a global variable (like window.JSLOADED) in myjs.js, with a true value, and create a timer (with setInterval) that check if JSLOADED == true. 
When myjs.js loads, it set JSLOADED, then you proceed with the rest.
Hope you solve it.

Comment: Hi Mauro, thanks for the answer. The problem here is that I will have <script scr="~/script/script.js"></script> twice or more times in the head element.